# Динамическое создание классов на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, orm

Необходимо реализовать ядро СУБД, работающее по принципу ORM. Интерфейс-класс-БД. Соответственно, необходимо создавать экземпляры класса для каждой записи БД. Как это организовать?

Comment: Те же классы можно заменить на словари и будет почти тоже самое :) А вообще, вы работали с ORM? Например, peewee или sql alchemy. Вы создаете класс, его название будет ассоциироваться с таблицей в базе, а его поля с полями таблицы. При select'е вы создаете класс и заполняете его поля по названию полей из результата select'а

Comment: так все таки динамическое создание классов? или экземпляров классов? слишком общий вопрос. с чем именно помочь? или мне все за вас сделать?)

Comment: 1) Нужно создать именно ядро, без участия посторонних либ вроде peewee.
2) Динамическое создание экземпляров. Вопрос именно в этом. Все остальное понятно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Стало любопытно и накидал простенький ORM. Но это именно **пример**, т.к. всего 2 типа поддерживается int и str, у полей нет всяких флагов типа уникальности или значения по умолчанию. Нет и связи между таблицами

*Пока писал думал о `peewee`, поэтому сделал базовую модель с `Meta` классом*

Пример:

```
import sqlite3

from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List


con = sqlite3.connect('test.sqlite')
con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row  # Чтобы получать из SELECT элементы как словари


class BaseModel:
    class Meta:
        db: sqlite3.Connection = con

    @classmethod
    def create_table(cls):
        con = cls.Meta.db

        fields = [f'{f.name} {"INTEGER" if f.type == int else "TEXT"}' for f in cls.__dataclass_fields__.values()]
        sql = f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {cls.__name__} ({', '.join(fields)})"
        print(f'[SQL]: {sql}')

        con.execute(sql)
        con.commit()

    def insert_db(self):
        self.create_table()

        cls = self.__class__
        con = cls.Meta.db

        fields = list(cls.__dataclass_fields__)
        values = [getattr(self, f) for f in fields]
        placeholders = ['?'] * len(fields)

        sql = f"INSERT INTO {cls.__name__} ({', '.join(fields)}) VALUES ({', '.join(placeholders)})"
        print(f'[SQL]: {sql}', values)

        con.execute(sql, values)
        con.commit()

    @classmethod
    def select_db(cls) -> List['BaseModel']:
        cls.create_table()
        con = cls.Meta.db

        sql = f"SELECT * FROM {cls.__name__}"
        print(f'[SQL]: {sql}')

        return [cls(**dict(row)) for row in con.execute(sql).fetchall()]


@dataclass
class Foo(BaseModel):
    name: str
    value: int


Foo(name='foo', value=123).insert_db()
print(Foo.select_db())

print()

Foo(name='bar', value=456).insert_db()
print(Foo.select_db())
```

Результат:

```
[SQL]: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Foo (name TEXT, value INTEGER)
[SQL]: INSERT INTO Foo (name, value) VALUES (?, ?) ['foo', 123]
[SQL]: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Foo (name TEXT, value INTEGER)
[SQL]: SELECT * FROM Foo
[Foo(name='foo', value=123)]

[SQL]: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Foo (name TEXT, value INTEGER)
[SQL]: INSERT INTO Foo (name, value) VALUES (?, ?) ['bar', 456]
[SQL]: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Foo (name TEXT, value INTEGER)
[SQL]: SELECT * FROM Foo
[Foo(name='foo', value=123), Foo(name='bar', value=456)]
```

Comment: Спасибо! В итоге решил заморочиться и почитать о peewee, сделал с его помощью. Так задачу решить оказалось проще

Comment: @Rizasto, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 4):

Хорошо. Вот у нас есть драйвер для работы с sqlite. Опустим проблемы с созданием схемы БД и миграциями. Пусть на данном этапе все это делается вручную.

```
import sqlite3
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class User:
    username: str
    password: str


conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("create table users (username varchar(512), password varchar(512));")
cursor.execute("insert into users (username, password) values ('test', 'test_pass');")
cursor.execute("select * from users;")
users = [User(*x) for x in cursor]
cursor.close()
conn.close()
print(users)  # [User(username='test', password='test_pass')]
```

Кажется это все. Делаете выборку и передаете результаты выборки в конструктор класса. Если я правильно понял вопрос.

Ну и на скорую руку набросал с созданием схемы)

```
import sqlite3
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class User:
    username: field(default_factory=str, metadata={"sqltype": "varchar(512)"})
    password: field(default_factory=str, metadata={"sqltype": "varchar(512)"})

    @classmethod
    def to_sql_query(cls):
        query = f"""
        create table {cls.__name__} ( 
        """

        fields = ",".join(f"{x[0]} {x[1].type.metadata['sqltype']}" for x in cls.__dataclass_fields__.items())
        query += fields
        query += ")"
        return query

    @classmethod
    def create_table(cls):
        return conn.execute(cls.to_sql_query())

    @classmethod
    def all(cls):
        cursor.execute(f"select * from {cls.__name__}")
        return [User(*x) for x in cursor]

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, username, password):
        return cursor.execute(f"insert into {cls.__name__} (username, password) values ('{username}', '{password}');")


conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cursor = conn.cursor()

User.create_table()
User.create("test", "test_pass")
users = User.all()

cursor.close()
conn.close()
print(users)
```

Настоятельно рекомендую использовать только в качестве примера.

Answer (score 1):

Экземпляр класса в основном нужно создавать для базы данных. Условно будет `class Database`. Внутри него будет инициализироваться подключение к базе данных проводить операции по занесению данных и исполнению скриптов, а также, что важно, корректное закрытие подключения.

Дальше у Вас будут классы или экземпляры моделей, это как реализуете. К примеру, пусть будет `class Model`. В нем у Вас будут храниться методы создания скриптов и работы с моделью типа `query, insert, delete, update, filter` и т.д., и т.п.

Дальше нужны классы `class Column` для создания колонок в таблице с различными опциями, а также классы типов полей (`Integer, Real, Text` и т.д.).

В качестве примера могу предложить вариант, который когда-то на курсах делал
https://github.com/ndrwpvlv/hatter_orm

Comment: Понравилась библиотека на гитхабе :)

Comment: Спасибо большое)